# Adding line and shapes to PDF document using MuPDF

Tags: java, android, mupdf

I am working on Mupdf library. I was able to build and run the application on my emulator. I need to allow the user to add lines and shapes to a PDF file. There is not adequate documentation regarding this on their website either.